# How to setup user notifications with multiple recipients and read status in MongoDB (Meteor app)

Tags: mongodb, meteor, notifications

In my Meteor app I have a mongo collection Notifications for user notifications, and I want to keep one document for one notification, even in case of multiple recipients. In each notification I have an array with users IDs. And I need to keep tack of read status for each user.

I tried to use an additional array to record who've read the notification like this:

```
{
  ...notification,
  users: [id1,id2,id3],
  read: [id2]
}
```

But two arrays cannot be indexed properly as I understand the docs. So my current approach is to have separate collection of UnreadNotifications with the documents referencing actual notifications by IDs and linking them to the users like this:

```
{
  notificationID: notificationid1,
  userID: id2
}
```

When the new notification created also a number of unread notification documents created for all the related users. When user reads a notification, the document is removed from mongo. Does this approach make sense? What are possible downsides?
The one issue I can think about is that user will probably have to fetch all of his unread notifications at once to be able to display witch of the real notifications are read. But it doesn't sound that bad.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, think from a client perspective. I need to get my notifications in the lightest way possible. I don't want other people's notifications, I don't want  to construct my data via aggregations.

Your Insert/create notification Meteor Method can have 2 function:

1. Insert the actual notification. If you have 10 people, 100 people, that is 10 ... 100 notifications.
2. On the user, write the increment of a notification count and eventually have it published with the other user details so that you can have it displayed.

When you open your notifications, you have a couple of options:

1. Read them all (write to db a "seen" or "read" field = Date.new() for these notifications. This field will help you style the notification as well seen - not seen.
2. Read on click of notification if in your UX a notification has to be opened. For example, I think in FB you have to click a notification to read it while in LinkedIn, opening notifications reads them all at once.
3. Use a library for in-view and only read those notifications that are in view, as you scroll in the list of notifications.

1 is the easiest to do and you also reset the counter on User to 0.

In summary, your insert notification method would be something like:

```
'methodName': async ({ notificationObject, userIds }) => {
   ...
   userIds.forEach(id => {
     - insert your notification
     - increment user counter
     - send a push notification
     - or send an email
   })

}
```

If you do this server-side and need to insert notifications from multiple methods such as: someone liked your something, someone sent a message to you etc... these are multiple methods that will be calling your insert notification method. In this case, if everything happens server side, better have the notification insert as a function instead of a method.